# workaround for absolute reference of named range in conditional format

Tags: vba, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

My working formula inside a macro for conditional formating is as follows:

```
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
    "=($C10<>"""")"
```

What I would like is to have `$C10` replaced by a named range. In case of new columns.

I.e `"=$MyRange_1.row(1)<>""""` 
Not sure if I will have to reference the first row, but this obviously doesn't work.

If it helps, the row number would always be 10

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff823060.aspx check this out for guidance

Comment: Thanks for commenting @mo.h ! But my brain didn't get how to translate that guidance into a working solution. Are you suggesting to create a new named range every time the macro is run, and use the named range as a parameter/formula?

Answer (score 0):

Heh,
I found out that I solved my question if I went into the name manager and changed the reference from an absolute to a relative reference...

That made the conditional formating work like a charm!